# How can i change dynamically the name of a question through google sheets using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to make a form where my partner can write a question on the google sheets and then the question automatically changes on the form
function updateForm() {

```
function updateForm() {

  //pergunta1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var setupSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Perguntas/Respostas");
  var langVals = setupSheet.getRange(2,2,setupSheet.getLastRow()-7,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(langVals);
  var form = FormApp.openById("1-_7qJ7W89pQ9yE6EN8HuePiegL1FdQcv6qwyBoB_igo");
  var langsMultipleChoiceQuestion = form.getItemById("611392210").asMultipleChoiceItem();
  langsMultipleChoiceQuestion.setChoiceValues(langVals);

//Pergunta2
  var langVals = setupSheet.getRange(2,3,setupSheet.getLastRow()-7,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(langVals);
  var form = FormApp.openById("1-_7qJ7W89pQ9yE6EN8HuePiegL1FdQcv6qwyBoB_igo");
  var langsMultipleChoiceQuestion = form.getItemById("1744979888").asMultipleChoiceItem();
  langsMultipleChoiceQuestion.setChoiceValues(langVals);

}
```

Comment: No i have only written code to get the options of the question but haven t find how to do the same for the content of the question.

Comment: i think i did it now.

Comment: Ok so what is the problem with this code - are you getting any specific error messages?

Comment: this code has no problem, but this is to extract the answers, so with this code when i change my google sheet it automatacly changes the options that apear on my form, but what i want now is to be able to change the question itself, but i cant find how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the title of an existing question you need to use the method `setTitle()`, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setTitle(String)). E.g.

`form.getItemById("1744979888").setTitle("This is the new question");`

You can also update the question with contents of a specific cell in your spreadsheet, for example with the content of the cell `A1` in your sheet:

`form.getItemById("1744979888").setTitle(setupSheet.getRange("A1").getValue());`